# Tomcat webapp error - application started thread [AWT-Windows] but has failed to stop it - memory leak?

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat, memory-leaks, awt

I didn't notice it until today during some testing locally on my pc, that Tomcat had posted an error in the log file. I'm using Tomcat 6.0.29 and Java JDK 1.6.

`Dec 1, 2010 12:36:57 pm org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading this Context has started
Dec 1, 2010 12:36:57 pm org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVER: The web application [/AutoSpyder] appears to have started a thread named 
[AWT-Windows] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory 
leak.`

What? I've never seen this before. So I checked my log file from yesterday, and sure enough, this error was there too. I don't quite understand what's causing this.

**Can I assume that it would have to be one of my servlets that uses objects from the `java.awt` package?** If so, how do I pinpoint the code that is causing this?

## Edited to add Thread Dump

```
2010-12-01 14:28:18
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (17.1-b03 mixed mode, sharing):

"JMX server connection timeout 34" daemon prio=6 tid=0x03069400 nid=0x960 in Object.wait() [0x0461f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on  (a [I)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ServerCommunicatorAdmin$Timeout.run(ServerCommunicatorAdmin.java:150)
    - locked  (a [I)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"RMI Scheduler(0)" daemon prio=6 tid=0x03069000 nid=0xe88 waiting on condition [0x045cf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for   (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:198)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2025)
    at java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue.take(DelayQueue.java:164)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:609)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:602)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:947)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.0.102" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0308a400 nid=0xebc runnable [0x0457f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
    - locked  (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:66)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:517)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    -  (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)

"RMI TCP Accept-0" daemon prio=6 tid=0x039e0c00 nid=0xc68 runnable [0x0452f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:390)
    - locked  (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:453)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:421)
    at sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept(LocalRMIServerSocketFactory.java:34)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:369)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:341)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"AWT-Windows" daemon prio=6 tid=0x02b65400 nid=0x7c4 runnable [0x042cf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(WToolkit.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Java2D Disposer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x02fccc00 nid=0x93c in Object.wait() [0x039df000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on  (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:118)
    - locked  (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:134)
    at sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Disposer.java:127)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-8080-6" daemon prio=6 tid=0x03322800 nid=0xfec in Object.wait() [0x0395f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on  (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:458)
    - locked  (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:484)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-8080-5" daemon prio=6 tid=0x02ba5c00 nid=0xdbc in Object.wait() [0x0390f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on  (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:458)
    - locked  (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:484)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-8080-4" daemon prio=6 tid=0x02ff6400 nid=0xa1c in Object.wait() [0x038bf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on  (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:458)
    - locked  (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:484)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-8080-3" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0317e400 nid=0x850 in Object.wait() [0x0386f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on  (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:458)
    - locked  (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:484)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-8080-2" daemon prio=6 tid=0x03314800 nid=0xf9c in Object.wait() [0x0381f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on  (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:458)
    - locked  (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:484)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-8080-1" daemon prio=6 tid=0x02efe800 nid=0x250 in Object.wait() [0x037cf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on  (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await(JIoEndpoint.java:458)
    - locked  (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:484)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"TP-Monitor" daemon prio=6 tid=0x02eed800 nid=0xd64 in Object.wait() [0x0375f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on  (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$MonitorRunnable)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$MonitorRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:565)
    - locked  (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$MonitorRunnable)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"TP-Processor4" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0318b000 nid=0x998 runnable [0x0370f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:390)
    - locked  (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:453)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:421)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.accept(ChannelSocket.java:312)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.acceptConnections(ChannelSocket.java:666)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketAcceptor.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:877)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"TP-Processor3" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0308f800 nid=0x92c in Object.wait() [0x036bf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on  (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:662)
    - locked  (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"TP-Processor2" daemon prio=6 tid=0x03192400 nid=0xfac in Object.wait() [0x0366f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on  (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:662)
    - locked  (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"TP-Processor1" daemon prio=6 tid=0x03182400 nid=0x8d8 in Object.wait() [0x0361f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on  (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:662)
    - locked  (a org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-8080-Acceptor-0" daemon prio=6 tid=0x03172400 nid=0xf04 runnable [0x035cf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:390)
    - locked  (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:453)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:421)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.acceptSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:61)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" daemon prio=6 tid=0x03163400 nid=0xbe8 waiting on condition [0x0357f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1579)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"GC Daemon" daemon prio=2 tid=0x0307bc00 nid=0x110 in Object.wait() [0x0349f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on  (a sun.misc.GC$LatencyLock)
    at sun.misc.GC$Daemon.run(GC.java:100)
    - locked  (a sun.misc.GC$LatencyLock)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Low Memory Detector" daemon prio=6 tid=0x02aecc00 nid=0x5b4 runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x02ae7000 nid=0x798 waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x02ae5800 nid=0xddc waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x02ae4000 nid=0xc00 runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Finalizer" daemon prio=8 tid=0x02add400 nid=0x378 in Object.wait() [0x02caf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on  (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:118)
    - locked  (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:134)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:159)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x02adbc00 nid=0x474 in Object.wait() [0x02c5f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on  (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:116)
    - locked  (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"main" prio=6 tid=0x002b7000 nid=0x14c runnable [0x0090f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:390)
    - locked  (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:453)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:389)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:662)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:614)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x02ada400 nid=0x210 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x02aefc00 nid=0x79c waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 1529
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try taking a thread dump to get a list of all the threads running on your server. From this, you may be able to pinpoint exactly which class started the thread based on the stack traces

### Windows

on the console window press `ctrl + break`

### Unix

in a command line enter:  `kill -3 <pid>`

Comment: I used VisualVM to do a thread dump - and I found an entry for "AWT-Windows", here's what it logged :    "AWT-Windows" daemon prio=6 tid=0x02b65400 nid=0x7c4 runnable [0x042cf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
 at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop(Native Method)
 at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(WToolkit.java:293)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
 - None

Comment: I'm no expert, so bare with me:) I'm not using any WToolKit objects in my classes...so why is this error popping up? Is it directly related to the fact that I'm running/testing my webapp through the 'localhost' tomcat server on my pc?

Comment: can you please put the full thread as an edit to your answer. Will make it easier to read there

Comment: Also while in VisualVM, If you monitor your application over a few days, how does your heap look?

Comment: I asked a question related to the heap and memory usage (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317535/java-memory-heap-and-webapp-analyzed-with-visualvm-are-the-results-normal) yesterday. When I make a request for a jsp page that has to load images from the db, a large amount of byte[] instances are created (according to VisualVM) and it does take awhile for the percentage of byte[] arrays to go down. But GC does eventually happen... I was trying to detect whether or not there was a leak somewhere in my classes - that's why I got VisualVM. My memory usage doesn't reach 100mb.

Comment: Your thread dump does look clean, and if you are not experienceing any major memory issues, I would assume your application will be fine. The message you found in your logs is INFO, so it is not an Error or Fatal exception. If you haven't done it already, use an application such as JMeter to load test your application and using VisualVM, you can profile what will be happening to your application under real load. Also in Tomcat, make sure to set the -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError flag. This way if you do run into memory problems, you will have a good starting ground for your analysis

Comment: Can I put the -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError flag in my tomcat.conf file on the vps...and then in startup.bat on my local pc? Is that the proper place for it?

Comment: Whereever you set your startup options, like -Xmx it would go in the same place. I am not familiar enough with your VPS setup to tell you otherwise

Comment: @Sean, in my TomEE 1.5.1 (tomcat 7.0.34) log, it is the following, SEVERE: The web application [/...] appears to have started a thread named [AWT-Windows] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

It's to do with Windows (i.e. MS Windows) and native calls to the underlying OS.  These would normally be GUI-type window operations, but could be other OS-specific things, e.g Clipboard or Font related, for instance.

If there's nothing obvious that you can see in your code that might relate to why it's being triggered, though, I'd not worry about it - that warning's more for the general case where spinning off new threads in a web-app isn't something you should be explicitly doing without a full appreciation of the potential issues.

Comment: When I saw this error, I was concerned that it would occur on my vps when the webapp runs live. There is only 1 servlet/class I have that uses java.awt classes, and its purpose is uploading/retrieving images (the actual image as bytes) from a db table...so I thought maybe that class was the trigger for this error. But your pretty certain that this error has to do more so with the fact that I'm running my app on my local pc...and the trigger is Windows related?

Answer (score 1):

We have tomcat server and jsf. JSF client will request images from the server and cause AWT-Windows thread to get started. Appears to cause a memory leak since threads contextClassLoader is the WebappClassLoader.

Looks like calling Java2DResource can caused AWT-Windows thread to be created -

Daemon Thread [http-8080-1] (Suspended (entry into method  in Thread))
    Thread.(Runnable, String) line: 444     <-- thread name is AWT-Windows
    WToolkit.() line: 244 
    NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Constructor, Object[]) line: not available [native method]
    NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Object[]) line: 39
    DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Object[]) line: 27
    Constructor.newInstance(Object...) line: 513 
    Class.newInstance0() line: 355
    Class.newInstance() line: 308
    Toolkit$2.run() line: 846
    AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction) line: not available [native method]
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit() line: 826
    D3DGraphicsDevice.() line: 47
    SurfaceManagerFactory.createCachingManager(BufferedImage) line: 48
    SurfaceManager.getManager(Image) line: 54
    SurfaceData.getDestSurfaceData(Image) line: 123 
    Win32GraphicsEnvironment(SunGraphicsEnvironment).createGraphics(BufferedImage) line: 389
    HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.createGraphics(BufferedImage) line: 76
    BufferedImage.createGraphics() line: 1137
    TabStripeImage(Java2Dresource).getImage(ResourceContext) line: 115
    TabStripeImage(Java2Dresource).send(ResourceContext) line: 89
    ResourceLifecycle.sendResource(ResourceContext, InternetResource) line: 219 
    ResourceLifecycle.send(ResourceContext, InternetResource) line: 158 
    InternetResourceService.load(Object, Object) line: 335
    LRUMapCache.load(Object, Object) line: 116
    LRUMapCache.get(Object, Object) line: 87
    InternetResourceService.serviceResource(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 195
    InternetResourceService.serviceResource(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 141
    Filter(BaseFilter).doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 508 
    Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 56
    SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 69
    LoggingFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 60
    SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 69
    SeamFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 158 
    ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 235
    ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 206
    StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 233
    StandardContextValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 191
    StandardHostValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 127
    ErrorReportValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 102
    AccessLogValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 555
    StandardEngineValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 109 
    CoyoteAdapter.service(Request, Response) line: 298
    Http11AprProcessor.process(long) line: 861
    Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(long) line: 579
    AprEndpoint$Worker.run() line: 1584 
    Thread.run() line: 619 [local variables unavailable]

Comment: What does this mean for me and my situation? I haven't seen an entry in the tomcat log for a warning on AWT before. The only classes I make use of from java.awt are the following : java.awt.geom.AffineTransform; java.awt.image.BufferedImage; java.awt.RenderingHints; java.awt.Graphics2D; java.awt.Image

The error I got refers to 
sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop(Native Method)
sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(WToolkit.java:293)

Can I assume then, that it has something to do with my local pc since it doesn't appear to happen on my remote vps?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are running JMX and I'm getting the impression that the Tomcat JMX server may be what's actually setting up the timer thread. In addition to the ones you mentioned in your parallel post on the JavaRanch, there's a java2D thread in the dump you have here.

I can't tell 100% because I don't know which threads were the parents for the orphan threads. If you could determine that, it would help.

Your Affine Transform is definitely pulling in graphics, however. It's a graphical function that will attempt to use your video card as a hardware accelerator. If you don't specify headless operation, it will tap into your windowing system to do so.

Comment: I am getting this error and I am running JMX on my production server all the time. It might be best for me to remove the JMX option from my JVM options, when starting Tomcat/TomEE on production server.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [this thread](http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/How-to-handle-the-AWT-Windows-thread-tp2054845p2054851.html) I found the following solution:

You only need to attach the AWT-Window-Thread to System-Classloader instead to  Wabapp-Classloader. You can do it in a ServletContextListener like this:

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent evt) {
    Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
    ClassLoader ccl = thread.getContextClassLoader(); // PUSH
    try {
        thread.setContextClassLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(new byte[]{});
    } finally {
        thread.setContextClassLoader(ccl); // POP
    }
}
```

Comment: I would not do this. setting the context to the system classloader makes it impossible to reload a application correctly inside a servlet container like Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running including some kind of graphical library like Jasper, JFreechart, LiquidOffice, StyleReport, ... that might interact  with AWT ?

Try starting tomcat by providing the -Djava.awt.headless=true property to see that gets rid of the exception

Comment: No, not running a graphical library of any kind. As far as using any classes from the java.awt packages, the only ones I use in 1 servlet are the following : java.awt.geom.AffineTransform, java.awt.image.BufferedImage, java.awt.RenderingHints, java.awt.Graphics2D, java.awt.Image

Comment: Locally, I startup tomcat through a dos prompt. So I did 'startup -Djava.awt.headless=true' - I'm assuming this worked since there wasn't any errors starting. The only thing I noticed was "usage: java org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina [ -config {pathname} ] [ -nonaming ] < -help : start : stop > at the top of output before tomcat started....